# Finding maximum value of unknown target function, given samples

Tags: python

I have a function that takes 4 variable and returns a single float value in range [0,1].

I want to know which inputs will maximize function's output. However, this function runs slow, so I just made 1000 random samples. i.e. 1000 tuples of (input, output)

Is there any good method to predict values that maximize my function with these tuples? I don't care if there are more function running, but not many.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What variable type are the inputs?

Comment: they're all floats,

Comment: The function you are describing sounds like a fitness function, you might want to take a look at Genetic Programming: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming

Comment: If your function is wrote in `numpy`, then try to use `matrix-op` other than` loop`.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no general method to do what you're asking.

[Global optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_optimization) is a collection of techniques (and a whole field of study) that are used to minimize a function based on some of its general properties.  Without more information about the underlying function, niave random sampling (as you're doing) is a 'reasonable' approach.

You're best best is to find additional information about the character of your function mapping (is the output spikey or smoothly varying with the input?  Are there lots of minima, or just a few?), or just keep sampling.